# Firefox Web Audio API on-the-fly update AudioBuffer / AudioBufferSourceNode

Tags: javascript, firefox, web-audio-api

I'm creating a 1s audio snippet by programmatically filling a `AudioBuffer`. The `AudioBufferSourceNode` has looping enabled. It plays back just fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Now I want to dynamically update the AudioBuffer and have the new audio picked up immediately (or at the next loop). In Chrome this works perfectly by simply getting the channel data (`getChannelData(0)`) and writing to it. Chrome updates the playing audio on-the-fly. Firefox keeps playing the original buffer over and over again. In fact in Firefox the `AudioBuffer` needs to be written before assigning it to the `AudioBufferSourceNode` (`source.buffer = buffer`).

Comment: This looks like unspecified behavior in the Web Audio spec. Maybe point out the implementation discrepancy at https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues and hope every browser does the same thing eventually?

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea the spec was on GitHub. I'll get involved. I'd generally love to be involved in new specs, but I'm not interested when it feels like the 90s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should not be done this way.  You're trying to update an object across a thread boundary.

Chrome has a bug where we don't currently implement the memory protection (i.e. you can update the contents of the AudioBuffer and it will change what the looping buffer sounds like).  FF currently has a different bug, where it allows you to set the .buffer more than once.  These should both get fixed.

To address this scenario, you need to loop each buffer until you get then next one, then cross-fade between them.  It's unlikely just looping a 1s buffer is really what you want anyway?  (unless it's noise.)

Comment: "unless it's noise": it's dynamically generated geiger counter knocks with changing frequency (via user interaction). 1s is fast enough reaction time to update the buffer with the new frequency (number of knocks per second)

Comment: Hmm.  Shouldn't have said "noise" - should have said "non-cyclic waveforms", and that qualifies.  I'd still recommend that you simply keep two buffers, and loop between them, updating the one you're not currently playing.

Comment: Just to clarify: that would mean constantly creating new `AudioBufferSourceNode`s and connecting them, right?

Comment: Every time you're swapping out the loop, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Simply assigning the same buffer again will update Firefox's internal state. So just do `source.buffer = buffer` again after updating the buffer. Even though it should be a NOOP, since it's the exact same reference.

Even `source.buffer = source.buffer` does the trick.

Comment: Note that this is a bug in Firefox's implementation, and therefore likely to get fixed.